# Partition allignment error. Offset issues

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 to a Seagate external hard drive. I have created a 30gb partition for the purpose. The rest is currently in use.

I selected a 25gb root partition and the rest is swap in the *something else* option.  It keeps throwing me partition alignment error.

I tried leaving empty partition in between, doesn't work. I DO NOT have the luxury to use the whole drive.

Since when did installing Ubuntu become so difficult? Where did the "install alongside Windows" option go?

Edit: solved

Comment: Since windows vendors started making installing linux systems difficult! Please can we see the whole partition scheme of your hdd or ssd?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! AFAIK the option “Install alongside Windows” is only displayed when Ubuntu knows how to partition your disk automatically which unfortunately seems to not be your case. Please boot live session (Try Ubuntu without installing), then run the commands `lsblk` and `sudo fdisk -l` and [edit] your post to add their output (as text). Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: I solved it. Used gparted to create partitions. Now Ubuntu is running perfectly from my external drive. Next step is to install the broadcom drivers for wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :- after booting from live usb. Open gparted and create partitions for / and swap manually and use the option to leave at least 1Mib in front of each partition.